# How to convert date string like "17-DEC-1980" into date format for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, date

I have some data and of the the format like `17-DEC-1980`. How can I convert it to Date object and insert into MongoDB?

Thanks.

Comment: WHat language/driver are you doing this in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript console (this code depends on timezones):

```
d = Date.parse('17-DEC-1980'); // 345844800000
```

Then this value put into mongodb request:

```
> new Date(345844800000)
ISODate("1980-12-16T20:00:00Z") // copy from MongoDB shell
```

Node.js (`example.js`) :

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    var mongodb = require('mongodb');
    var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});
    new mongodb.Db('se', server, {}).open(function (error, client) {
      if (error) throw error;
      var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection');

      d = Date.parse('17-DEC-1980');
      collection.insert({dt: new Date(d)}, {safe:true}, function(err, objects) {
        if (err) console.warn(err.message);
        if (err && err.message.indexOf('E11000 ') !== -1) {
          // this _id was already inserted in the database
        }
      });
    });

  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```